# On exponentials of real skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

Let $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the algebra of $n\times n$ matrices with real coefficients, equipped with the operator norm, with respect to the $\ell^2$ norm $\displaystyle\|x\|_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$, namely $\displaystyle\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2$.

Let $\displaystyle\exp(A):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}$ be the exponential map on $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Let $A(n)$ be the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices $A=-A^T$.

Let $O(n)$ be the group of orthogonal matrices $A=(A^T)^{-1}$, and let $SO(n)$ be its subgroup made of determinant 1 matrices.

Now take $1\leq k\leq n-1$ and consider:

- $A(k,n)=\{[a_{ij}]\in A(n)\,:\, a_{ij}=0 \mbox{ for }i\leq k<j\mbox{ and }j\leq k<i\}$
- $X=\{[a_{ij}]\in A(n)\,:\, a_{ij}=0 \mbox{ for }i,j\leq k\mbox{ and }k<i,j\}$

In other terms $A(n)=A(k,n)\oplus X$ according to the block decomposition:
$\begin{bmatrix}A_1&A_3\\A_2&A_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A_1&0_{k\times(n-k)}\\0_{(n-k)\times k}&A_4\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0_{k\times k}&A_3\\A_2&0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)}\end{bmatrix}$

**Remark:** It is clear that $\exp(X)\exp(A(k,n))\subset SO(n)$.

**Claim:** For every $T\in SO(n)$, there exist $B\in X$ and $A\in A(k,n)$ such that $\|B\|\leq \pi$ and $\exp(B)\exp(A)=T$.

**Question:** How would you establish this claim? If possible, I'd like to see different approaches (diagonalization, Lie algebra arguments, ...).

Comment: 1. Your $A(n)$ is, in fact, $o(n)$, the Lie algebra of $O(n)$. Why not use the established notation? 2. Your current definition of $A(k,n)$ is, *probably*, not what you want: if $i \le j$ then the second part of the conjunction defining it (which implies $j < i$) will never happen, therefore $A(k,n) = \emptyset$. Maybe you meant $\min(i,j) \le k < \max(i,j)$ (which is equivalent to using "or" instead of "and")?

Comment: @AlexM. 1. There are many possible notations that would be more appropriate. I have just decided to keep those used in the paper I read. 2. I meant $a_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$ such that $1\leq i\leq k<j\leq n$ and all $i,j$ such that $1\leq j\leq k<i\leq n$.